# Can't Get TiledMap Object's Properties

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to `cocos2d-iphone` and I'm trying to learn TiledMap.
I was following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29458/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x) tutorial to make a simple tiled map game.
Everything was good until the "Tiled Object Layers and Setting Tile Map Position" section.
I couldn't get the objects `x` and `y` properties, they return `0` instead of the real coordinates.

Here is my `init` method

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        self.map = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"Map.tmx"];
        self.bgLayer = [map layerNamed:@"bg"];

        CCTMXObjectGroup *objects = [map objectGroupNamed:@"oj"];
        NSMutableDictionary *startPoint = [objects objectNamed:@"StarPoint2"];

        int x = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"x"] integerValue];
        int y = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"y"] integerValue];

        sylvester = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sylvester.jpg"];
        sylvester.position = ccp(x, y);

        [self addChild:sylvester];
        [self addChild:map z:-1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of the problem but when I created a new project the problem is fixed.